# helm variables in .Values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to dynamically generate my template file, here is my case:

```
{{- $v := (.Files.Get "values-deployment-nginx.yaml") | fromYaml }}
spec:
  {{- range $key, $value := $v.containers }}
  containers:
  - name: {{ $value.name }}
    image: {{ .Values.{{ $value.name }}-image }}:{{ .Values.{{ $value.name }}--tag }}
```

I want to first get the {{ $value.name }}, it maybe a string like "nginx", then I would like to use the {{ .Values.nginx-image }} to get the right image value in values file.
Is there a way can do this? Thank you very much!

---

I have many deployment template dynamically generated, but **only want to expose the image and tag to values file** , so that we can pass different image informations when install chart. Other variables are in (.Files.Get "values-deployment-nginx.yaml") , like this(is also generated dynamically).   So when generate the template, I want to match the image and tag in value file.

values file like this:

```
deployment-nginx-imagerepo: nginx
deployment-nginx-imagetag: latest
```

values-deployment-nginx.yaml like this(generated by other project):

```
autoscale: []
containers:
- envs: []
  imagerepository: nginx
  imagetag: latest
  itemid: n79fecd51_6716_fa65_5e64_aeed8ed6ab7e
  name: nginx
  resource:
    maxcpu: ""
    maxmemory: ""
    mincpu: "0.5"
    minmemory: 512m
  volumemounts: []
name: details
replicas: 1
schedulpolicy: []
storages: []
type: deployment
```

Answer (score 6):

In the [Go text/template language](https://godoc.org/text/template) I believe the `index` function will do this.  (`.Values` is typically a map, and YAML maps and lists convert to Go maps and slices.)  (Also remember almost everything in the [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) library is available.)

```
image: {{ index .Values (printf "%s-image" $value.name) }}:{{ index .Values (printf "%s-tag" $value.name) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to define a helper.

Let's assume we're passing in image info in a values file at runtime that defines a dictionary map of versions by target environment (namespace) and service (chart name).

e.g.,

```
DEV:
  appA: a.b.c/path/to/appA:1.2.3
  appB: a.b.c/path/to/appB:2.2.1
QA:
  appA: a.b.c/path/to/appA:1.2.1
  appB: a.b.c/path/to/appB:1.8.1
```

This defines namespaces `DEV` and `QA`, each with services `appA` and `appB`.

In my `templates/_helpers.tpl` files:

```
{{/* Look up image spec from the runtime values file. */}}
{{- define "appB.refSpec"                              -}}{{*/ or appA /*}}
{{-   $targetEnv := index .Values .Release.Namespace    }}
{{-   get $targetEnv .Chart.Name                        }}
{{- end                                                 }}
```

Then in `templates/deployment.yaml`:

```
image: "{{ include "appB.refSpec" . }}"
```

Now when deploying:

```
helm upgrade -i -n DEV appB myRepo/appB -f v.yml
```

The `refSpec` helper will assign `$targetEnv` the `DEV` map from `.Values`, then pass back the `appB` value from it to the `image:` field for deployment.

If we maintain that file in a git repo, then every change can go through pull request review and approval, and it's easy to clone at runtime in an automation.

You may not need that much complexity, but it lets you encapsulate it when you do. :)