# Helm Interpolation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am setting the following environment variable in Helm Deployment like so.

```
name: SERVER_ENDPOINT
value: {{ .Values.server.dev_proxy_endpoint }}
```

But would like to interpolate the environment part (dev) of the value variable, like so

```
name: SERVER_ENDPOINT
value: {{ .Values.server. {{ .Values.environment | lower }} _proxy_endpoint }}
```

Is this possible?

## Reply to first comment

I tried that out by creating a new definition at the top of the file like so:

```
{{- $value_path_to_endpoint := print ".Values.server." .Values.environment  "_proxy_endpoint" -}}
```

But that then presents a literal value, rather than the context pointer to the values file.

```
name: SERVER_ENDPOINT
value: {{ $value_path_to_endpoint}}
```

In other words, $value_path_to_endpoint returns:

```
".Values.server.dev_proxy_endpoint"
```

Rather than

```
.Values.server.dev_proxy_endpoint
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333336/helm-variables-in-values

Answer (score 3):

You can use `index` function from [Go text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and Helm's [printf function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#printf)

```
env:
- name: SERVER_ENDPOINT
  value: {{ (index .Values.server (printf "%s_proxy_endpoint" ( .Values.environment | lower ))) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look around, and it looks like that this is possible. This article here explains how a few other people have achieved the same :)

[Kubernetes Helm, combine two variables with a string in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278655/kubernetes-helm-combine-two-variables-with-a-string-in-the-middle)